# Python stops without errors

Tags: python, sql

I have 9 Raspberry Pi connected to 9 machines physically (via cables). These Raspberry Pi collects data from these machines and send it to MQTT broker (mosquitto-Server) running on different PC (Lets call it Server PC). The script which I posted above runs on Server PC. I run this script with the help of Python IDLE. Also, the script was running fine some days ago but I changed the following things:
Previously there were 4 on_message callbacks which I made it to 1.
A Little sophisticated way to check the Connection to the Clients (by sending Server/Connection).
The script above runs on Python shell till 1-2 Hours but suddenly it stops without Errors.

```
# Import libraries.....
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import pyodbc
import datetime
import sqlite3

# ------------- Global Variable Declaration ----------------
LastTime1 = 0
LastTime2 = 0
LastTime3 = 0
LastTime4 = 0
LastTime5 = 0
DeltaT1 = 5
DeltaT2 = 10
DeltaT3 = 20
DeltaT4 = 5
DeltaT5 = 300
Days = 180
w = 3
Clients = 9
Data = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(Clients+1)]
for y in range (1,Clients+1):

    Data[y][0] = "Client"+str(y)
    Data[y][1] = False
    Data[y][2] = 0

# -----------------------------  MQTT callbacks -------------------------------

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('Connected with result code {0}'.format(rc))
    for y in range (1,Clients+1):
        client.subscribe(Data[y][0]+"/#")


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global Data
    myTopic = str(msg.topic)
    myTopic=myTopic[myTopic.index("/")+1:len(myTopic)]
    myText=str(msg.payload)   
    myText=myText[myText.index("'")+1:len(myText)-1]
    cursor1 = connection.cursor()

    for y in range (1,Clients+1):
        if msg.topic == Data[y][0]+"/TimeData":
            Data[y][1]=True           # Connection
            Data[y][2]=time.time()    # Last Message

    if myTopic == 'TimeData':
        print("------------------------------------------------ Time Data ---------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
        myText1=myText.split(",")
        print(myText)
        try:  #  Database
            cursor1.execute("INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.TimeData (CTime, Unit, CycleCount,Ur, CycleTime, ClientId, PTopic, IpAdress, Perc, DeltaTUpl, DeltaPh, Reason) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6], myText1[7], myText1[8], myText1[9], myText1[10], myText1[11]))

            connection.commit()
            print("Database - XDB01 OK")

        except:
            print('------------ >>>>  Error Database - XDB01')
            try:
                #OpenDb2
                cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO TimeData (CTime, Unit, CycleCount,Ur, CycleTime, ClientId, PTopic, IpAdress, Perc, DeltaTUpl, DeltaPh, Reason) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                    (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6], myText1[7], myText1[8], myText1[9], myText1[10], myText1[11]))        
                connection2.commit()
                print("Database Buffer ok")
                #closeDb2
            except:
                print("Error Buffer Database")


    if myTopic == 'MachineData':
        print("------------------------------------------------------ Machine Data -------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
        myText1=myText.split(",")

        try:  #  Database                                             1         2   3   4  5      6      7    8     9     10    11      
            cursor1.execute("INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.MDaten (CTime,MText,Ip,Ml,Temp1,Temp2,Temp3,Temp4,Temp5,Temp6,Temp7,Text1,Value1, DeltaTUpl, DeltaPulse) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6], myText1[7], myText1[8], myText1[9], myText1[10], myText1[11],myText1[12],myText1[13],myText1[14]))        

            connection.commit()
            print("Database - XDB01 OK")

        except:
            print('------------ >>>>  Error Database XDB01')
            try:
                #OpenDb2
                cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO MachineData (CTime,Unit,Ip,Ur,Temp1,Temp2,Temp3,Temp4,Temp5,Temp6,Temp7,Text1,Value1, DeltaTUpl, DeltaPulse) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                    (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6], myText1[7], myText1[8], myText1[9], myText1[10], myText1[11],myText1[12],myText1[13],myText1[14]))        
                connection2.commit()
                print("Database Buffer ok")
                #CloseDb2
            except:
                print("Error Buffer Database")


    if myTopic == 'PlcData':
        print("-------------------------------------------- Plc Data --------------------------------------------------------------\n")
        myText1=myText.split(",")
        print(myText)
        try:  #  Database 

            cursor1.execute("INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.PlcDaten (PTime,MText,Ip,Ml,Prod,Status1,Status2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6]))        

            connection.commit()
            print("Database - XDB01 OK")
        except:
            print('------------ >>>>  Error Database XDB01')
            try:
                #OpenDb2           
                cursor2.execute("INSERT INTO PlcData (CTime,Unit,IpAdress,Ur,Prod,Status1,Status2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                    (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6]))            
                connection2.commit()
                print("Database Buffer OK")
                #CloseDb2
            except:
                print("Error Buffer Database")



    if myTopic == 'QualityData':
        print("----------------------------------------------- Quality Data -----------------------------------------------------------------\n")

        myText1=myText.split(",")
        print(myText)
        try:  #  Database
##        if True:

            cursor1.execute("""INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.QualityData
               ([QTime],[UnitId],[Status_HS],[WT_bestückt],[WT_vorh],[WT_IO],[WT_NIO],[WT_NIO_Station],[WT_Fehlercode],[WT_Nummer],[WT_Teile_vorh],[WT_falscher_Typ],[Lauf_Nummer]
               ,[M03_Stückzahl],[M03_Nietzeit],[M03_Rohmass],[M03_Fertigmass],[M03_Nietdruck],[M03_Motordrehzahl],[M04_Stückzahl],[M04_Nietzeit],[M04_Rohmass],[M04_Fertigmass]
               ,[M04_Nietdruck],[M04_Motordrehzahl],[M05_Stückzahl],[M05_Nietzeit],[M05_Rohmass],[M05_Fertigmass],[M05_Nietdruck],[M05_Motordrehzahl],[M06_Stückzahl],[M06_Nietzeit]
               ,[M06_Rohmass],[M06_Fertigmass],[M06_Nietdruck],[M06_Motordrehzahl],[M08_Schweissbuckel_1],[M08_Schweissbuckel_2],[M08_Schweissbuckel_3],[M08_Schweissbuckel_4]
               ,[M08_Schweissbuckel_5],[M08_Schweissbuckel_6],[M08_Schweissbuckel_7],[M08_Schweissbuckel_8],[M08_Schweissbuckel_9],[M08_Schweissbuckel_10],[M08_Schweissbuckel_11]
               ,[M08_Schweissbuckel_12],[M08_Schweissbuckel_13],[M08_Schweissbuckel_14],[M08_Schweissbuckel_15],[M08_Schweissbuckel_16],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_1],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_2]
               ,[M08_Nietkopf_DM_3],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_4],[M08_Ebenheit],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_1],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_2],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_3],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_4],[M08_Gesamtbreite_1]
               ,[M08_Gesamtbreite_2],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_1],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_2],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_3],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_4], [M08_Abstand_Bohrung_1], [M08_Abstand_Bohrung_2]
               ,[Produkt_Nummer], [Fehler_Code])
               VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",
                (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6], myText1[7], myText1[8], myText1[9], myText1[10], myText1[11], myText1[12]
                 , myText1[13], myText1[14], myText1[15], myText1[16], myText1[17], myText1[18], myText1[19], myText1[20], myText1[21], myText1[22], myText1[23], myText1[24], myText1[25]
                 , myText1[26], myText1[27], myText1[28], myText1[29], myText1[30], myText1[31], myText1[32], myText1[33], myText1[34], myText1[35], myText1[36], myText1[37], myText1[38]
                 , myText1[39], myText1[40], myText1[41], myText1[42], myText1[43], myText1[44], myText1[45], myText1[46], myText1[47], myText1[48], myText1[49], myText1[50], myText1[51]
                 , myText1[52], myText1[53], myText1[54], myText1[55], myText1[56], myText1[57], myText1[58], myText1[59], myText1[60], myText1[61], myText1[62], myText1[63], myText1[64]
                 , myText1[65], myText1[66], myText1[67], myText1[68], myText1[69], myText1[70], myText1[71]))        

            connection.commit()
            print("----------------------------------------Done-----------------------------------------------")
            print("Database - XDB01 OK")

        except:
            print('------------ >>>>  Error Database XDB01')
            try:
                #OpenDb2
                cursor2.execute("""INSERT INTO QualityData
                   ([QTime],[UnitId],[Status_HS],[WT_bestückt],[WT_vorh],[WT_IO],[WT_NIO],[WT_NIO_Station],[WT_Fehlercode],[WT_Nummer],[WT_Teile_vorh],[WT_falscher_Typ],[Lauf_Nummer]
                   ,[M03_Stückzahl],[M03_Nietzeit],[M03_Rohmass],[M03_Fertigmass],[M03_Nietdruck],[M03_Motordrehzahl],[M04_Stückzahl],[M04_Nietzeit],[M04_Rohmass],[M04_Fertigmass]
                   ,[M04_Nietdruck],[M04_Motordrehzahl],[M05_Stückzahl],[M05_Nietzeit],[M05_Rohmass],[M05_Fertigmass],[M05_Nietdruck],[M05_Motordrehzahl],[M06_Stückzahl],[M06_Nietzeit]
                   ,[M06_Rohmass],[M06_Fertigmass],[M06_Nietdruck],[M06_Motordrehzahl],[M08_Schweissbuckel_1],[M08_Schweissbuckel_2],[M08_Schweissbuckel_3],[M08_Schweissbuckel_4]
                   ,[M08_Schweissbuckel_5],[M08_Schweissbuckel_6],[M08_Schweissbuckel_7],[M08_Schweissbuckel_8],[M08_Schweissbuckel_9],[M08_Schweissbuckel_10],[M08_Schweissbuckel_11]
                   ,[M08_Schweissbuckel_12],[M08_Schweissbuckel_13],[M08_Schweissbuckel_14],[M08_Schweissbuckel_15],[M08_Schweissbuckel_16],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_1],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_2]
                   ,[M08_Nietkopf_DM_3],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_4],[M08_Ebenheit],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_1],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_2],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_3],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_4],[M08_Gesamtbreite_1]
                   ,[M08_Gesamtbreite_2],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_1],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_2],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_3],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_4], [M08_Abstand_Bohrung_1], [M08_Abstand_Bohrung_2]
                   ,[Produkt_Nummer], [Fehler_Code])
                   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",
                    (myText1[0], myText1[1], myText1[2], myText1[3], myText1[4], myText1[5], myText1[6], myText1[7], myText1[8], myText1[9], myText1[10], myText1[11], myText1[12]
                     , myText1[13], myText1[14], myText1[15], myText1[16], myText1[17], myText1[18], myText1[19], myText1[20], myText1[21], myText1[22], myText1[23], myText1[24], myText1[25]
                     , myText1[26], myText1[27], myText1[28], myText1[29], myText1[30], myText1[31], myText1[32], myText1[33], myText1[34], myText1[35], myText1[36], myText1[37], myText1[38]
                     , myText1[39], myText1[40], myText1[41], myText1[42], myText1[43], myText1[44], myText1[45], myText1[46], myText1[47], myText1[48], myText1[49], myText1[50], myText1[51]
                     , myText1[52], myText1[53], myText1[54], myText1[55], myText1[56], myText1[57], myText1[58], myText1[59], myText1[60], myText1[61], myText1[62], myText1[63], myText1[64]
                     , myText1[65], myText1[66], myText1[67], myText1[68], myText1[69], myText1[70], myText1[71]))

                connection2.commit()
                print("Database Buffer OK")
                #CloseDb2
            except:
                print("Error Buffer Database")


# ------------------------ MQTT connection ------------------------
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect  # Specify on_connect callback
client.on_message = on_message  # Specify on_message callback

try:
    print("Connecting to MQTT")
    client.connect('localhost', 1883, 60)
except:
    print("Error connecting to MQTT")

client.loop_start()
connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=XDB01;'
                      'Database=Production_DE;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
connection2 = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/xabreoli/Documents/PythonFiles/PythonProg/Production_DE.db")
cursor2 = connection2.cursor()


# --------------------------------------------- Main loop -----------------------------------
while True:

    # -------------------- Send Server Online and Time to Clients --------------------
    if (time.time()-LastTime1)>=DeltaT1:
        client.publish('Server/Connection', 'Online')
        client.publish('Server/Time', str(time.time()))
        LastTime1=time.time()

    # -------------------- Check connection to Clients --------------------
    if (time.time()-LastTime2)>=DeltaT2:
        for y in range (1,Clients+1):
            if time.time() - Data[y][2] > 65:
                Data[y][1] = False           # Connection

            print(Data[y][0]+" Connection : "+str(Data[y][1]))

        LastTime2=time.time()


    # -------------------- Restore buffered Data --------------------
    if (time.time()-LastTime4)>=DeltaT4:

##        try:
        if True:
            cursor2.execute("select * from TimeData")
            rows = cursor2.fetchall()
            print("Buffer Database - TimeData has "+str(len(rows))+" rows to restore")            
            if len(rows)>0:
                print("Restoring TimeData")
                sqlcmd="INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.TimeData (CTime, Unit, CycleCount,Ur, CycleTime, ClientId, PTopic, IpAdress, Perc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                cursor1.executemany(sqlcmd,rows)
                connection.commit()
                cursor2.execute("delete from TimeData")
                connection2.commit()

            cursor2.execute("Select * from MachineData")
            rows = cursor2.fetchall()
            print("Buffer Database - MachineData has "+str(len(rows))+" rows to restore")
            if len(rows)>0:
                print("Restoring MachineData")
                sqlcmd="INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.MDaten (CTime,MText,Ip,Ml,Temp1,Temp2,Temp3,Temp4,Temp5,Temp6,Temp7,Text1,Value1, DeltaTUpl, DeltaPulse) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                cursor1.executemany(sqlcmd,rows)        
                connection.commit()
                cursor2.execute("delete from MachineData")
                connection2.commit()

            cursor2.execute("Select * from PlcData")
            rows = cursor2.fetchall()
            print("Buffer Database - PlcData has "+str(len(rows))+" rows to restore")
            if len(rows)>0:
                print("Restoring PlcData")
                sqlcmd="INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.PlcDaten (PTime,MText,Ip,Ml,Prod,Status1,Status2) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
                cursor1.executemany(sqlcmd,rows)        
                connection.commit()
                cursor2.execute("delete from PlcData")
                connection2.commit()

            cursor2.execute("Select * from QualityData")
            rows = cursor2.fetchall()
            print("Buffer Database - QualityData has "+str(len(rows))+" rows to restore")
            if len(rows)>0:
                print("Restoring QualityData")
                sqlcmd=("""INSERT INTO Production_DE.dbo.QualityData
                            ([QTime],[UnitId],[Status_HS],[WT_bestückt],[WT_vorh],[WT_IO],[WT_NIO],[WT_NIO_Station],[WT_Fehlercode],[WT_Nummer],[WT_Teile_vorh],[WT_falscher_Typ],[Lauf_Nummer]
                           ,[M03_Stückzahl],[M03_Nietzeit],[M03_Rohmass],[M03_Fertigmass],[M03_Nietdruck],[M03_Motordrehzahl],[M04_Stückzahl],[M04_Nietzeit],[M04_Rohmass],[M04_Fertigmass]
                           ,[M04_Nietdruck],[M04_Motordrehzahl],[M05_Stückzahl],[M05_Nietzeit],[M05_Rohmass],[M05_Fertigmass],[M05_Nietdruck],[M05_Motordrehzahl],[M06_Stückzahl],[M06_Nietzeit]
                           ,[M06_Rohmass],[M06_Fertigmass],[M06_Nietdruck],[M06_Motordrehzahl],[M08_Schweissbuckel_1],[M08_Schweissbuckel_2],[M08_Schweissbuckel_3],[M08_Schweissbuckel_4]
                           ,[M08_Schweissbuckel_5],[M08_Schweissbuckel_6],[M08_Schweissbuckel_7],[M08_Schweissbuckel_8],[M08_Schweissbuckel_9],[M08_Schweissbuckel_10],[M08_Schweissbuckel_11]
                           ,[M08_Schweissbuckel_12],[M08_Schweissbuckel_13],[M08_Schweissbuckel_14],[M08_Schweissbuckel_15],[M08_Schweissbuckel_16],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_1],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_2]
                           ,[M08_Nietkopf_DM_3],[M08_Nietkopf_DM_4],[M08_Ebenheit],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_1],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_2],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_3],[M08_Aufnahmebohr_4],[M08_Gesamtbreite_1]
                           ,[M08_Gesamtbreite_2],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_1],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_2],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_3],[M08_Tiefe_Kalotte_4], [M08_Abstand_Bohrung_1], [M08_Abstand_Bohrung_2]
                           ,[QData3], [QData4], [QData5], [Produkt_Nummer], [Fehler_Code], [QData8],[QData9],[QData10] )
                           VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""")
                cursor1.executemany(sqlcmd,rows)        
                connection.commit()
                cursor2.execute("delete from QualityData")
                connection2.commit()

##        except:
##            ("Waiting to connect to the XDB01 Database")

        LastTime4=time.time()

 '''
```

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by Python? Might be useful to also take a look at the usage metrics of the PC running the script. It might be out of memory/...

Comment: How are you running the script? From the command line?

Comment: I am running the script on Python Shell

Comment: What is "Python Shell" here? How do you literally start it? `python script.py` in a command prompt window? If so, it _will_ show you a traceback if it crashes.

Comment: It is an in-built Python IDLE which is installed along with the Python

Comment: Run in the command prompt instead, then, to have one less possible source of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

That might not debug it for you, see if you can use WING to debug it on the fly.
Ref# [here](http://wingware.com/hints/raspberry-pi)

The Raspberry Pi is not really capable of running Wing itself, but you can set up Wing on a computer connected to the Raspberry Pi to work on and debug Python code remotely.

Comment: also check if there are any connection time outs set at the SQL db level.

Comment: WING isn't required for debugging – Python ships with `pdb`, which is spartan but a debugger nevertheless...

Comment: sure! but do checkout the connection timeouts at SQL layer as well, that can close the connections consistently if its there. See if there is a pattern in the connection closure.

Comment: I have also tried to reconnect to SQL DB if the Connection is lost but still doesn't solve my Problem.